# create numeric vector based on values in logic vector- R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have a logic vector in R something like this:

```
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [55] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [73] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I want to construct another *numeric* vector that contains a 1 if the logic vector is true and a 0 if it is false. I have tried the following code

```
## create an empty vector
numericvec <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)

## for loop
for (i in logicvec){
  if(i == TRUE){
    c(numericvec, 1)
  } else {
    c(numericvec, 0)
  }
}
```

The for loop syntax seems ok because I don't get errors when I run it but it isn't currently adding any values to the numeric vector.

Comment: Just do `as.integer(logicvec)` or `+(logicvec)`

Comment: To explain why `numericvec` is never appended ... it's because you never assign it. Your method (which is *very* inefficient in R) should more appropriately be `numericvec <- c(numericvec, 1)`. But that is very very inefficient in R. It is much better to use @akrun's suggestion.

Comment: Using for loops for this kind of operation is generally unnecessary and inefficient in R because the language is largely vectorized.  It looks like you're speaking R with a C accent.  See "Hands-On Programming with R" by Garrett Grolemund, page 183, Loops Versus Vectorized Code. https://d1b10bmlvqabco.cloudfront.net/attach/ighbo26t3ua52t/igp9099yy4v10/igz7vp4w5su9/OReilly_HandsOn_Programming_with_R_2014.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
numericvec <- as.numeric(logicvec)
```

No need for a `for()` loop. R typically operates on entire columns.